# Passing C# datetime value to Oracle DB Query

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I have a SQL query that I am passing a C# variable into my Oracle DB.

I am having trouble passing a C# datetime variable, "PROCESS_DATE", into my query in my application.  I do not get any records back.  If I copy the query into my oracle developer tool, TOAD, it works fine and I get multiple records.

Here is the query I am using in my application:

```
String SelectAllSQL = "SELECT * FROM REALMS_AUDIT.R2_GROUP_QUERY_RPT WHERE PROCESS_DATE = :pPROCESS_DATE";
```

I also tried converting the datetime variable into a shortDateString() so it matches the database exactly I then used the TO_DATE function, which I have to use if I query dates directly in TOAD, without any luck.  The shortDateString() changes my date into: `1/16/2016`, which is what I need, but the OracleDataReader does not like it.  Here it the query with the TO_DATE function:

```
String SelectAllSQL = "SELECT * FROM REALMS_AUDIT.R2_GROUP_QUERY_RPT WHERE PROCESS_DATE = TO_DATE(:pPROCESS_DATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY'";
```

`:pROCESS_DATE` is a datetime variable that is passed in.

There must be a breakdown between C# and Oracle in relation to handling a datetime variable.  *I am using Oracle DataReader* to handle the processing of the query.

```
OracleDataReader dataReader = mDataAccess.SelectSqlRows ( oracleConnection, oracleCommand, sqlCommand, parameters );

        while ( dataReader.Read ( ) )
        {
                groupEntityFacilityRptList.Add ( ReadRecord ( dataReader ) );
        }
```

If I use the TO_DATE function, the application will not step into the while loop.  If I use the original query, it does but returns no data.

**The datetime variable PROCESSDATE looks like this:**

```
1/16/2016 12:00:00 AM
```

I notice it has a timestamp on it, so I'm not sure if that is the problem or not.
**The data in Oracle is like this:**

```
1/16/2016
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your programm in order to see if your ".ToShortDateString()" gets you the "1/16/2016" your database needs? Sometimes there can be errors concerning other time formats (CultureInfo etc.).

Comment: Yes, it puts it in that format: 1/16/2016 like I need.  The problem seems to be with passing that into the query.

Comment: Do you use the class "SqlConnection" with DataSource etc.? If you use SqlConnection, use also the class "SqlCommand". This allows you to add the parameters with i.E. cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", varDate); and execute your operation like this: "SELECT * FROM ... WHERE Date = @Date", so there is really no chance that the values are getting messed up.

Comment: Can you try as `TRUNC(TO_DATE(:pPROCESS_DATE,'MM-DD-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'))`

Comment: @AbdulHameed I'm getting not a valid month.  Could there be an issue with January being displayed at "1" instead of "01"?  Thanks

Comment: are you sure your message format is 1/16/2016 12:00:00 AM and not 16/1/2016 12:00:00 AM? Can you retry with `TRUNC(TO_DATE(:pPROCESS_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'))` and see this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, please try below and see this resolves.

`TRUNC(TO_DATE(:pPROCESS_DATE,'MM-DD-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'))` if `pROCESS_DATE` format is `1/16/2016 12:00:00 AM`.

`TRUNC(TO_DATE(:pPROCESS_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'))` if `pROCESS_DATE` format is `16/1/2016 12:00:00 AM`.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I've totally misunderstood your issue, I think you might be making this harder than it needs to be.  ODP.net handles all of that dirty work for you.  If `PROCESS_DATE` is an actual `DATE` datatype in Oracle, then you just need to pass an actual C# `DateTime` variable to it and let ODP.net do the heavy lifting.  There is no need to do conversion of any type, provided you are passing an actual date:

```
DateTime testDate = new DateTime(2015, 7, 16);

OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(
    "SELECT * FROM REALMS_AUDIT.R2_GROUP_QUERY_RPT WHERE PROCESS_DATE = :pPROCESS_DATE",
    conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("pPROCESS_DATE", OracleDbType.Date));
cmd.Parameters[0].Value = testDate;

OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    object o = reader.IsDBNull(0) ? null : reader.GetValue(0);
}

reader.Close();
```

If your data in C# is not a date, I'd recommend making it one before even trying:

```
DateTime testDate;
if (DateTime.TryParse(testDateString, out testDate))
{
   // run your query
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I learned that my code will not go into the code below unless I actually have records returned to me.

```
OracleDataReader dataReader = mDataAccess.SelectSqlRows ( oracleConnection, oracleCommand, sqlCommand, parameters );

        while ( dataReader.Read ( ) )
        {
                groupEntityFacilityRptList.Add ( ReadRecord ( dataReader ) );
        }
```

Second, to get ProcessDate to work, I needed to take the string that was coming from my View, convert it to a datetime, and then I formatted it back as a string.  It may not be best practices but it worked.

```
public JsonResult GetGroupReportData ( String reportDate )
{
  DateTime processDate = DateTime.Parse ( reportDate );
  var monthlyReport = SelectAllGroupRprt (processDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

  return new JsonResult ( )
    {
      Data = monthly,
      MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue
    };
}
```